# C++ memory Alignment on a 64 bit machine

Tags: c++, memory

```
Class A
{
  public:
    void fun1();
    void fun2();

  private:
     uint16 temp_var;
};
```

Is there any reason why I shouldn't just make this variable uint16 to full uint64?  Doing it this way (uin16), do I leave memory "holes" in the object ?, and I'm told the processor is more efficient in dealing with full uint64s.
for clarification, temp_var is the only member variable. And no where i was using it for size(temp_var) or as a counter to loop back to zero

Thank you all for your inputs, appreciate it..

Comment: Please clarify if you are interested specifically in the case where the variable is the only class member.

Comment: One reason not to do that would be if you want to guarantee that the variable will only ever hold values between 0 and 65535, inclusive (i.e. you want temp_var++ to "wrap" back to zero when you increment it past 65535).  You wouldn't get that behavior by default with a uint64.

Comment: Or.. if you ever serialize `temp_var` and don't want your data to be 4 times the size it should be.

Comment: *"I'm told the processor is more efficient in dealing with full uint64s"* - You have been told incorrectly.

Comment: In general, you rarely have to worry about optimizing or controlling the padding of data structures to get more harmonious memory alignment. The compiler typically takes care of this for you - by placing member variables of class/struct instances on natural boundaries for the size of the variable. You can influence the padding optimizations to a degree by the declaration ordering of the members in a class, but it's only a micro-optimization that is worthwhile when you scale up.  For a class with only a single variable, there's not much to optimize on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is, can the compiler do the substitution:

You asked for a `uint16` so it gave you a `uint16`. It would be surprising to get something else.

For instance, imagine if a developer was counting on a behavior of integer overflow or underflow. In that case, if the compiler substituted a `uint64` behind the scenes, then that would be problematically surprising for the developer.

Along the same lines, one would expect `sizeof(temp_var)` to equal `sizeof(uint16)`.

There are probably further cases in which such a substitution could lead to unexpected behavior that wouldn't be anticipated by the developer.

---

If the question is, can you the developer pick something else:

Sure, you can if you want a variable of that size. So then how about some possibilities where you wouldn't...

If you rely on overflow/underflow behavior of a `uint16` then of course you would want to stick to that.

Or perhaps this data is going to be passed along to some further location that only supports values in the range of a `uint16`, so leaving it that size may make logical sense to try to implicitly document what's valid and/or avoid compiler warnings.

Similarly you might want for `sizeof(temp_var)` to be 2 bytes instead of 8 for some logical reason relevant to other parts of the program.

I also expect there are some games one could play with the packing pragma, but I presume that isn't relevant to the intended question.

Depending on the goal of your program, logical consistency or clarity of code may be more important than maximum possible performance (especially at the micro level of being concerned about size/type of a member variable). To phrase that another way, `uint16` is still fast enough for many many use cases.

In some situations though, there won't be any compelling reason to make the decision one way or the other. At that point, I would go with whatever seems to make the most sense as per personal sensibilities.

Comment: I think the questioner meant "is there any reason I, the programmer, shouldn't change `temp_var` to type `uint64`", not if there was any reason why the compiler shouldn't do that.

Comment: Fair enough, I was thinking in terms of a differing meaning of "we".